# Proof of a Complex Conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

I am told to prove the following:

$$
\exp(\overline{z}) = \overline{\exp(z)}\,\!
$$

for all $z$ in the complex plane.

In what direction can I expand the equation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
If $z=x+iy$,
$$e^z=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)),$$
and $\sin$ is an odd function, $\cos$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

$$\overline{\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{z^k}{k!}}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\overline{z}^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: To this I would add that conjugation is a continuous function. ${}\qquad{}$